# TensorFlow: Why do parameters not update when GradientDescentOptimizer train step is run?

Tags: tensorflow

When I run the following code, it prints a constant loss at every training step; I also tried printing the parameters, which also do not change. 
I can't seem to figure out why `train_step`, which uses a `GradientDescentOptimizer`, doesnt change the weights in W_fc1, b_fc1, W_fc2, and b_fc2.
I'm a beginner to machine learning so I might be missing something obvious.
(An answer for a similar question was that weights should not be initialized at zero, but the weights here are initialized with truncated normal so that cant be the problem).

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np
import csv
import random 
with open('wine_data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
  input_arr = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))
for i in range(len(input_arr)):
  input_arr[i][0] = int(input_arr[i][0]) - 1 # 0 index for one hot
  for j in range(1, len(input_arr[i])):
    input_arr[i][j] = float(input_arr[i][j])

random.shuffle(input_arr)
training_data = np.array(input_arr[:2*len(input_arr)/3]) # train on first two thirds of data
testing_data = np.array(input_arr[2*len(input_arr)/3:]) # test on last third of data

x_train = training_data[0:, 1:]
y_train = training_data[0:, 0]

x_test = testing_data[0:, 1:]
y_test = testing_data[0:, 0]

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)
def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 13], name='x')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name='y_')
y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(y_, tf.int32), 3) # actual y values
W_fc1 = weight_variable([13, 128])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([128])
fc1 = tf.matmul(x, W_fc1)+b_fc1

W_fc2 = weight_variable([128, 3])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([3])
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(fc1, W_fc2)+b_fc2) 


cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_one_hot, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-17).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_one_hot,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train})
  if _%10 == 0:
    loss = cross_entropy.eval(feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train})
    print('step', _, 'loss', loss)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your learning rate is really small. What happens if you use 1e-4?

Comment: That seems to have been part of the problem. When I reduce the learning rate to 1e-4, occasionally the loss diminishes slightly over time, but it seems that with most random weight initializations, the loss does not change.

Answer (score 0):

From the official tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits):

> WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.

Remove the softmax on y before feeding it into `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`

Also set your learning rate to something higher (like 3e-4)